# Enable Counter only for number input field in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create an input field to enter marks rating of university (GPA). So I need a validation for the input and if possible to disable input only and change value from step counter.

```html
<input type="number"
       min="1"
       max="4"
       placeholder="Desired Rating"
       disabled={true}
       step="0.01"
/>
```

I have to add the validation using regex in which I can enter number between range of 4.00 to 1.00 with decimal point enable as well

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the keyboard event, then you will input number only by the up down button.

```
yourInput.addEventListener('keydown', e => e.preventDefault())
```

btw, seems you don't need an input, use a slider instead. see this https://ant.design/components/slider/